# O servidor Apache é necessário em serviços de hospedagem?

Tags: apache, servidor

O servidor web Apache ou o XAMPP é a mesma coisa que o UOL Host ou qualquer outro provedor de hospedagem, ou seja, a finalidade dos dois é armazenar sites e retornar as requisições feitas pelo navegador?

Por exemplo, se eu contratar o UOL Host ou o Terra para hospedar meu site, essas empresas não precisarão do Apache ou do XAMPP para completar a requisição feita pelo navegador? Ou até eles têm que acessar o Apache?

Comment: Xampp nao e um servidor http, xampp e um pacote de programas que combina apache, mysql, php e perl. Sim servidores online usam apache ou ngnix ou lighttpd. Um servidor se parece com um computador normal, no entanto a infra e diferente, o sistema operacional e voltado pra servidores e muitas vezes ele e virtualizado (shared ou vps) e usam apache (ou ngnix ou lighttpd). Se for uma aplicacao Java ele pode usar tomcat ou jboss (faz algum tempo que nao uso), geralmente estes servidores sao "like-unix", existem tambem servidores windows que usam IIS geralmente.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

Um servidor HTTP sempre será necessário para atender requisições vindas de navegadores ou outros clientes que façam uso de comunicação pelo [protocolo HTTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

Um desses servidores é o Apache, que é um dos componentes do XAMPP. Até onde eu sei, em certos tipos de planos de hospedagem o fornecedor citado usa Apache e em outras o IIS da Microsoft. Pode ser que usem outras coisas em determinadas situações.

O XAMPP costuma ser usado apenas durante o processo de desenvolvimento do site.

Certamente eles não têm instalado o XAMPP. Este é um apanhado de softwares que facilitam leigos usarem de forma mais fácil. Eles podem até ter os mesmos componentes instalados lá, mas de outra forma. Lá tem profissionais que sabem instalar e operar tudo de forma personalizada e não precisam de nada tão pronto assim.

Lembrado que o XAMPP é apenas um desses *bundles* de softwares para desenvolvimento web e pode-se usar outros componentes.

É possível a própria aplicação funcionar como um servidor HTTP, mas não costuma ser o caso da maioria delas e especialmente você não vai fazer isto nestas hospedagens compartilhadas. Isto é algo bem mais avançado e você precisa ter controle sobre o ambiente de "hospedagem", além de muito conhecimento do que está fazendo.

Se tiver outras dúvidas específicas, abra outras perguntas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se alguém viu algo errado na resposta, favor informar para eu consertar. Principalmente quem negativou.

Answer (score 6):

O provedor da sua hospedagem já está equipado com tudo. É independente de sua máquina. O **XAMPP** é usado para rodar sites localmente, em sua máquina.

O **XAMPP** é um ambiente de teste entre outras coisas.

Se você contratar o UOLHOST ou outro provedor não precisa se preocupar se você tem o **XAMPP** ou não.

Answer (score 0):

O Apache e o XAMPP são ferramentas que estão relacionadas à criação e hospedagem de sites, mas têm funções diferentes em contextos diferentes.

1. **Apache:**
   O Apache HTTP Server (ou simplesmente Apache) é um servidor web de código aberto amplamente utilizado. Ele é projetado para servir páginas web e atender a solicitações HTTP feitas pelos navegadores. O Apache é instalado e configurado em um servidor para permitir que ele hospede sites. Quando você acessa um site em seu navegador, o servidor Apache processa a solicitação e retorna a página da web correspondente.
2. **XAMPP:**
   O XAMPP é um pacote de software que inclui o Apache, MySQL, PHP e outras ferramentas necessárias para executar um ambiente de servidor local em seu computador. É frequentemente usado para desenvolver e testar sites ou aplicativos antes de implantá-los em um servidor web real.
3. **UOL Host, Terra e outros provedores de hospedagem:**
   Empresas como UOL Host, Terra e outros provedores de hospedagem oferecem serviços de hospedagem na web. Eles fornecem servidores configurados para hospedar sites e aplicativos. Esses provedores geralmente cuidam da configuração do servidor, segurança, manutenção e outras tarefas relacionadas à hospedagem. Eles usam servidores web (como o Apache) e outras tecnologias nos bastidores para fornecer os serviços de hospedagem.

Quando você contrata um provedor de hospedagem, eles cuidam de toda a infraestrutura necessária para que seu site seja acessível na internet. Você não precisa se preocupar com a instalação e configuração do Apache ou de outras ferramentas de servidor web. A empresa de hospedagem já configura esses serviços para você. Ao acessar seu site através do navegador, as solicitações passam pelo servidor web configurado pela empresa de hospedagem.

Portanto, ao contratar um serviço de hospedagem, você não precisa se preocupar com a instalação e configuração do Apache ou do XAMPP. O provedor de hospedagem lida com esses aspectos técnicos para que você possa se concentrar em criar e gerenciar o conteúdo do seu site.